# How to clear a .csv column in powershell ? I have a csv file and i need to clear 2 columns without deleting the column

Tags: powershell

I have a .csv file and I need to change the header of the columns and empty the 2 last columns without deleting the entire column. just the contents of the 2 last columns.

I was able to successfully update the headers of the column, but I am unable to clear the contents of the two last column.

```
Import-Csv     -path 'C:\Users\mbaylosi\Desktop\Trrimblepowershell\mqb_costcode.csv' |
select -Property @{label="CodeID";expression={$($_."ClientName")}},
@{label="CodeDescription";expression={$($_."ClientCode")}},
@{label="StartDate";expression={$($_."Location")}},
@{label="EndDate";expression={$($_."ClientDisabled")}} |
Export-Csv     C:\Users\mbaylosi\Desktop\Trrimblepowershell\TEST\mqb_costcode.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I expect that the headers are updated and the 2 last columns are empty.

Comment: what are the 1st three rows if the INPUT csv & the same rows in the output?

Comment: Just to be clear, a `.csv` file can only handle strings. So, `empty` will mean an empty string even you assign a `$Null` to the concerned property as @LotPings shows it will be eventually casted to a zero length string if you export it to a `.csv`.

Comment: @iRon Good point. So better: Do the same as with your other calculated properties `@{label="LastColumn";expression={""}}`